# How can I Give the togglebutton a default text?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, togglebutton

I have a togglebutton with this style shown below, the toggle button work perfectly but I would like to set a default text to the togglebutton when I open the MainWindow , it should be shown that in the state of false, not disabled

The togglebutton will show the text value only when I do action on it ( Set to ON or OFF ) it will display the text but by default, it seems to the user that it was disabled ( see the picture ).

**After starting the application :**

[image]

**Set ON :**

[image]

**Set OFF:**

[image]

The problem is when I run the application before click on the Toggle button , the shown in the screen is a Tooglebutton was disabled , I need to inizialize this control to state "OFF" ,

Is it possible?

How can I do that?

**App.xaml**

```
  <Style x:Key="myToggleSwitch" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Grid x:Name="toggleSwitch">
                        <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="10"
        Background="#FFFFFFFF"
        Width="80" Height="25">
                            <Border.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0.5" Direction="0" Opacity="0.3" />
                            </Border.Effect>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Stretch="Uniform"
             Margin="2 2 2 1"
             Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="0.2"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="22" >
                                <Ellipse.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="1" Opacity="0.3" Direction="260" />
                                </Ellipse.Effect>
                            </Ellipse>
                        </Border>

                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtOff" Text="OFF" Margin="0 0 40 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="DemiBold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="White" FontSize="12" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtOn" Text="ON" Margin="40 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="DemiBold"  Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="12" />
                    </Grid>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True" >
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>

                                <BeginStoryboard>

                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                To="#34A543"
                                Duration="0:0:0.1" />

                                        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                    To="56 2 2 1"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="txtOff" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                            From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:0:0.1"     />
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="txtOn" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                            From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0:0.1"  />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <!--  some out fading  -->
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                To="#C2283B"
                                Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                    To="2 2 2 1"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="txtOff" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                            From="0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0:0.1"       />
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="txtOn" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                            From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:0:0.1" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource IdealForegroundColorBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource GrayBrush7}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
  <Grid>
    <ToggleButton  x:Name="tog" Style="{StaticResource myToggleSwitch}" Width="150" Checked="tog_Checked" Unchecked="tog_Unchecked" ></ToggleButton>
</Grid>
```

**Update :**

```
<Style x:Key="myToggleSwitch" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/> <!-- What I have added -->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Grid x:Name="toggleSwitch">
                        <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="10"
        Background="#FFFFFFFF"
        Width="80" Height="25">
                            <Border.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0.5" Direction="0" Opacity="0.3" />
                            </Border.Effect>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Stretch="Uniform"
             Margin="2 2 2 1"
             Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="0.2"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="22" >
                                <Ellipse.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="1" Opacity="0.3" Direction="260" />
                                </Ellipse.Effect>
                            </Ellipse>
                        </Border>

                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtOff" Text="OFF" Margin="0 0 40 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="DemiBold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="White" FontSize="12" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtOn" Text="ON" Margin="40 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="DemiBold"  Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="12" />
                    </Grid>
```

**Update 2** ( Testing the solution of Jason ).

This what I got :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to put in your style `<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>`? BTW that toggle button looks really nice, well done

Comment: Yes, the style code was from internet , I have mentionned in previous question the source of the code that I have used , it looks good but it have only this problem.

Comment: Sorry but there is no `IsSelected` property in ToggleButton

Comment: Then use IsChecked instead, sorry

Comment: No problem , I have add it now and it does not work ( I mean `IsChecked` property ).

Comment: Please Update your question with code you added

Comment: I have updated my question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your colors are set by reacting to the `IsChecked` state change, you just need your initial values to match the `false` state. Set the border color to the off color (red) rather than white. That should get you what you're looking for.

```
<Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Grid x:Name="toggleSwitch">
                  <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="10"
                          Background="#C2283B"
                          Width="80" Height="25">
  ...
</Setter.Value>
```

Also set the default opacity of the "On" text to 0 to prevent it from showing.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtOn" Text="ON" Opacity="0" Margin="40 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="DemiBold"  Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="12" />
```

[image]

Comment: No , it show for me ON and OFF with red color , if you change the width of the ToggleButton you will see this problem .

Comment: Wow strange, I get the results I posted. I don't know why we'd get different results; that's odd. Well if you go ahead and also default the `Opacity` of txtOn to 0, it should work for ya. Although based on your screenshot, the text location of "Off" also seems incorrect. Again strange, the storyboards don't move the text Hmm.

Comment: No this was not strange , if you change the width you will get the same result that I got , try and you will see

Comment: This work for short strings ( if states was "ON"and "OFF" )

Comment: I see. You've got a lot of hard-coded sizes, I assumed this was a fixed size control. To make it more dynamic, wouldn't you need to replace those fixed widths/margins? But at this point it seems we're beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: I will give you upvote because this is only work for short words but not for word that have many characters

Comment: OK thanks. For completeness, I added the part about also setting the "On" text opacity to 0. But yeah, once the text sizes start to grow, they will get clipped. Putting the text in the border and allowing the border to auto size to the content could help with that. Good luck.